# Splitting Tables in Html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

I use MySQL. I wrote an html code with a php file extension. There is a table in the code, but the table is too long. Is there a way to split the table and make it page by page? I want to use JavaScript. If you have some more information, Ask in the comments.
I'll write some more empty informations for posting, it returns with error

My Index.php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES UTF8");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$datas = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $datas);  
?>

<html lang="tr" dir="ltr">
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thesselia Öğrenci DataBase</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Thesselia's DataBase</a>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/list.php">Listele</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/ekle.php">Ekle</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/guncelle.php">Güncelle</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/sil.php">Sil</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h2>Thesselia'nın Öğrenci Bilgileri DataBase'sine hoş geldiniz!</h2>
    <table>
     <tr>
        <th>Sıra No</th>
        <th>Cinsiyet</th>
        <th>Isim</th>
        <th>Soyisim</th>
        <th>Tc Kimlik No</th>
        <th>Anne Adı</th>
        <th>Baba Adı</th>
        <th>Güvenlik NO</th>
        <th>Doğum Tarihi</th>
        <th>Doğum Yeri</th>
     </tr>
    <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td> " . $row["Sira_no"]. "</td>
    <td> " . $row["Cinsiyet"]. "</td>
    <td> " . $row["Isim"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Soyisim"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Tc_kimlik_no"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Anne_adi"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Baba_adi"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Guvenlik_no"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Dogum_tarihi"]. "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Dogum_yeri"]. "</td></tr>";

  }
?>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a library that could make life easier if you generate tables with php.

I recommend that you use a JavaScript library called DataTable

you just have to assign an ID to the table and in javasctipt generate the datatable instance... this will automatically generate the pagination of the table.

I share an example of how you should instantiate the datatable in Javascript

```
$('#idtabla').dataTable();
```

Here is the link to their official page:

https://datatables.net/